# Conditional delete metadata does not works

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I would like to remove some metadata if I save post with another metadata with custom post type in my plugin.. I tried to use init hook and iterate array from get_posts function but it doesn't work and too I tried with save_post hook but it doesn't work too..

Attaching action in my __construct function (in class with plugin functions):

```
add_action('save_post_survey', [$this, 'survey_start_type_validation']);
```

And here I trying to check if metadata exists and if yes, then delete the old:

```
function survey_start_type_validation($post_id)
    {
            $type_of_running = get_post_meta($post_id, 'spusteni_dotazovani');

            if($type_of_running == 'manually_run') {
                if(metadata_exists($post_id, 'datum_a_cas_planovaneho_spusteni')) {
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'datum_a_cas_planovaneho_spusteni');
                }
            } elseif($type_of_running == 'planned_run') {
                if(metadata_exists($post_id, 'running_status')) {
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'running_status');
                }
            }

    }
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.. Can anyone advice me?

Comment: Have you check the function paramaters in wordpress documentation? seems like you are passing the incorrect arguments to it, `metadata_exists( string $meta_type, int $object_id, string $meta_key )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying these and your code might work:

1. Looking at the expressions `$type_of_running == 'manually_run'` and `$type_of_running == 'planned_run'`, where you're expecting [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to return a single meta value, you should then set the 3rd parameter to `true`:

   ```php
   // Set the 3rd param to true to get a single meta value.
   $type_of_running = get_post_meta($post_id, 'spusteni_dotazovani', true);
   ```
2. [`metadata_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/) requires 3 parameters, i.e. the meta type (e.g. `post` for post meta or `term` for term meta), the "object" ID (e.g. post ID or term ID) and the meta key, so make sure you pass the correct parameters like so:

   ```php
   if(metadata_exists('post', $post_id, 'datum_a_cas_planovaneho_spusteni')) {
       delete_post_meta($post_id, 'datum_a_cas_planovaneho_spusteni');
   }
   ```

   and

   ```php
   if(metadata_exists('post', $post_id, 'running_status')) {
       delete_post_meta($post_id, 'running_status');
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me so much.. :)